# Extract a sub string between : and WORD in java using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract text between semi colon (;) and WORD. i am using below code but unable to extract "TVS A3003" using below code.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=;).*?(?=WORD)").matcher(string);
```

Three Sample strings :

```
1. (XYZTRR: KTTT 4.0.1; TVS A3003 WORD/LLLLL ; pj ;) 

2. (XcdcdRR; dTff 5.4.1; TVS A3003 WORD/UJH;KKKHH fpp) 

3. LLLhf22; 776332 8.7.1; TVS A3003 WORD/UHHGFVV phhp

4. (;LLLhf22; 776332 8.7.1; TVS A3003 WORD/UHHGFVV phhp ;)
```

I want to extract TVS A3003 in all the cases.

Comment: Post the full relevant code. What exactly does not work?

Comment: find the answer for the exact question below

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Hi , the link shared by you is failing for the 3rd sample and giving output as "776332 8.7.1; TVS A3003 "

Comment: You may solve it with `(?<=;)[^;]*?(?=WORD)` or `;([^;]*?)WORD`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot Wiktor. the above regex is working for all the three sample. Can you suggest a regex for 4th sample string as well?

Comment: @MohitAgrawal [Same as in my answer](https://regex101.com/r/q6A7TC/2)

Comment: There is no difference between the 4th and the other 3 strings, see the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FLGbcI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a `;` and then match any 0+ chars other than `;` as few as possible up to the first occurrence of `WORD`. You may do that using

```
;([^;]*?)WORD
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6A7TC/1). Note that the leading/trailing whitespace can be easily trimmed off with `.trim()` after a match is found.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Fi054x) below:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("(XYZTRR: KTTT 4.0.1; TVS A3003 WORD/LLLLL ; pj ;)", 
        "(XcdcdRR: dTff 5.4.1; TVS A3003 WORD/UJHKKKHH fpp)",
        "(LLLhf22; 776332 8.7.1; TVS A3003 WORD/UHHGFVV phhp) );");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";([^;]*?)WORD");
while (String s : strs) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim()); 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
TVS A3003
TVS A3003
TVS A3003
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. the above regex is working for all the three sample. Can you suggest a regex for 4th sample string as well?

Comment: @MohitAgrawal There is no difference between the 4th and the other 3 strings, see the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FLGbcI).

Answer (score 0):

reg ex is **`(?<=KTTT 4\.0\.1; )(.*)(?= WORD/U)`**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=KTTT 4\\.0\\.1; )(.*)(?= WORD/U)").matcher(string);

if(matcher.find()){
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```